# How to get the row number of tr elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Code:

```
function removeTds() {
    var elements = $('#goldBarList tr:not(:eq(0))').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked):lt(100)');
    var count = elements.length;
    elements.remove();
    if (count === 100) 
        window.setTimeout(removeTds, 1);
}
removeTds();​
```

How can I know the row numbers which are in the `elements` variable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood your question right, you can use `index`:

```
elements.each(function(){
    console.log($(this).index());
});
```

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: @thecodeparadox, well you know... here and there, discovered the world outside stackoverflow... it's a nice world. :)

Comment: @gdoron yeap... me too in same situation... glad to hear you.. thx! :)

Answer (score 0):

use [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/);

```
elements.each(function(){
   var rowindex=$(this).index()
});
```